# Omit odbc dialog during program execution

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, odbc

The following is the code I use in order to access an MS Access Database via ODBC. What I want to achieve is that the ODBC dialog is not coming up.

Please see here for the content of the ppF.dsn file:
Please replace "odbc: " by "https://". I don't know how else to make a file available! Please also note: The download link for ppf.dsn will expire On May 13, 2023!
odbc we.tl/t-0toIuEBMOW

My suspicion is that this is related to the Connection string.
Please help with this.

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------
//#include "pch.h"
//#include "Db.h"

// pch.h: This is a precompiled header file.

#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

// add headers that you want to pre-compile here
#include "framework.h"

#endif //PCH_H

#pragma once
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <afxdb.h>

class CDb : public CDatabase
    {
    protected:
      int m_iPrice;
      const CString m_strSQL = L"SELECT Pay FROM tblOptions;";
      CString strDsn;
    public:
      void setPrice();
      int getPrice();
      CDb();
      virtual ~CDb();
  };

void CDb::setPrice()
    {
    CString strDriver(L"Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, 
*.accdb)");
    CString strFile(L"C:\\ExamplePath\\pp.accdb");
    //
    //strDsn.Format(L"ODBC;DRIVER={%s};DBQ=%s;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;", 
    //strDriver, strFile);
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    // With this connectin string coming from 
    //https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb- 
    //odbc-driver/
    // no exception is thrown, but the odbc dialog comes up as 
    // before. 
    strDsn = L"ODBC;FileDSN=ppf;Driver={Microsoft Access Driver 
    (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; 
    Dbq=C:\\ExamplePath\\app\\pp.accdb; 
    Uid=Admin;Pwd=1234;";
    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    //Open(NULL, false, false, strDsn);
    // --------------------------------------------
    // no more exception with above strDsn!!!
    // but odbc dialog is coming up at rs.Open ...
    // == Here an exception is thrown ==
    OpenEx(strDsn, strDsn, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
    // ---------------------------------------------
    CRecordset rs;
    // At this point the ODBC dialog opens
    rs.Open(CRecordset::dynaset, m_strSQL);
    CString strField;
    rs.GetFieldValue(short(0), strField);
    m_iPrice = _tstoi(strField);
    rs.Close();
    Close();
    }


int CDb::getPrice()
    {
    return m_iPrice;
    }

CDb::CDb()
    {
    setPrice();
    }

CDb::~CDb()
    {
    m_iPrice = 0;

    if(IsOpen())
        Close();
    }

 // The following is a code sample FormView to display data 
 // from the MS Access Database

Cmain1View::Cmain1View() noexcept
: CFormView(IDD_MAIN1_FORM)
, m_strText(_T(""))
{
CDb* pDb = new CDb();
CString m_strText;
m_strText.Format(L"%d", pDb->getPrice());
delete pDb;
pDb = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `OpenEx()` member instead, it takes an options argument, you have to add the `CDatabase::noOdbcDialog` option.

The connection-string must contain enough information, for the credentials dialog not to be needed. Add the following part to your connection string `;Uid=%s;Pwd=%s`. The username and password must be read from some configuration file or registry entries (there are security considerations here, but this is out of the scope of this question).

Alternatively, if you can override the member of your database class that makes the connection (you will have to dig into the MFC sources), you can change the code so that it calls the `SQLDriverConnect()` function with the `SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT` option included.

---

### EDIT:

Checked your code again, and I have some comments to make:

- There is no point in both using a `FILEDSN` (or `DSN`) and specifying the data-file in your connection string. These do specify the data-file, among others.
- The `CRecordset` constructor takes a `CDatabase*` argument which associates it with a database object - typically previously opened, ie succesfully connected to a database. If omitted (defaults to NULL), it will create a temporary DB object and attempt to connect it. Try passing the CDb object you created there (since this is called from within a CDatabase-derived object, you can use `this`).
- The `OpenEx()` call is the preferred method of opening a database, per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdatabase-class?view=msvc-170#open).
- Because opening a database (establishing a connection) is a resource-heavy task, this is usually performed once (eg during app initialization) and closed just before the app exits (or when it's no longer needed), instead of connecting/disconnecting for every DB operation. Therefore I would move the open/close code out of the `setPrice()` method (which is a read operation, so it should rather be named `readPrice()` or something, but this is another matter...)

Comment: I did the following:   strDsn.Format(L"ODBC;DRIVER={%s};DBQ=%s;", strDriver, strFile);
  LPCWSTR pctwDsn(strDsn.GetString());
  OpenEx(pctwDsn, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
and a breakpoint was executed. Is it possible that this is related to the missing **Uid=%s;Pwd=%s**? I left them out, because in the ODBC dialog I set both to: **''** (two single quotes)

Comment: Don't know, sorry. It's quite strange that you are using quotes in a dialog box. I think they are not needed even inside the connection string. So try empty values (`Uid=;Pwd=;`) and if this doesn't work either, try `Uid=Admin;Pwd=;` - this is supposed to open the database with "Standard Security". Also experiment with and without quotes. It may be weird to find that the username and password you put into the database are actually a pair of single quotes instead of empty strings

Comment: I will do. Currently I don't have no Windows, so I cannot do the modification right now. But thank you. I will try all your suggestions out. I will acknowledge your answer in the near future (might be a week or so).Thank you, again.

Comment: Please check above code changes: An exception is thrown. In order to verify that my dsn string worked I replaced the OpenEx with Open as in the original question. In the odbc32 (64 bit option) I replaced user by nothing and the same with password!

Comment: Don't really know, sorry. You can make some short tests, with a new db file containing a true username and password, then with (really) empty ones, not quotes. I have used it this way (username + password) and it worked, but it was a long time ago and the database was MS-SQL, not Access.

Comment: Yes, I tried this connection string: L"ODBC;FileDSN=ppf;Driver={Microsoft Access Driver 
        (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; , I got the string from https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/ , but still have the same problem: odbc dialog is coming up. So back to my question: What is wrong with the connect string. Please see in the code: I added ODBC;FileDSN=ppF. This is what is missing for me. Thank you for your efforts

Comment: I installed Access 2010 64 bit drivers, because "somebody" said so and get the error message: "Datasource name not found and no default driver specified". My odbc.ini seems to ignore my newly installed 64 bit drivers: [ODBC 32 bit Data Sources]
ppM=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb) (32 bit)
[ppU]
Driver32=C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\OFFICE14\ACEODBC.DLL

Anybody? Please.

Comment: @Michaelinscarbororough, did you check the EDIT in my post? The ODBC dialog should NOT be displayed when calling `CRecordset::Open();` (`rs.Open()` in your code) ie that `// At this point the ODBC dialog opens` should not happen. The ODBC dialog should only be displayed during the `CDatabase::Open()` (or `OpenEx()`) call - this is what you want to avoid too of course (it's what your question is about) and it can be solved by properly installing/configuring the drivers and passing a correct connection-string.

Comment: Hi Constantine, this nailed it. creating the CRecordset using the CDatabase object did the job. Thank you so very much.